# PostgreSQL Resourse Limitations in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I run PostgreSQL 15 in Kube. So in heavy loads, when RAM usage reaches to 100% the WAL writer crushes and aborts. Because of the pid existance it never comes up again without intervention. So ideally I would like to limit its RAM (like we can do with cgroups in linux) let's say for 90% usage. So I would like to hear what is the best way to limit CPU and RAM usage of a PostgreSQL cluster in a pod. I think here the cgroups would not be a good solution as without pod restart PostgreSQL restart could be dangerous.

Comment: The WAL writer uses 100% RAM?  That seems very unlikely.  How did you determine this?

Comment: No, you got wrong the question. It's just crushing because of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, cgroups is an extremely bad way to manage memory for PostgreSQL. It gives you two choices:

- processes exceeding the limit are killed by the OOM killer
- processes exceeding the limit freeze until other processes free memory

The first will crash PostgreSQL (but it will come up again unless you misconfigured it), and the second is also not a viable solution.

The trick is to configure `shared_buffers`, `work_mem`, `max_connections`, `maintenance_work_mem` and `hash_mem_multiplier` so that PostgreSQL never touches the limit. "Unused" memory is no problem, since PostgreSQL will use it for caching.

There is no safe rule to size these parameters, but a rule of thumb that works in most cases is

`shared_buffers` +
2 * `work_mem` * `max_connections` +
`maintenance_work_mem` * `autovacuum_max_workers` ≤ RAM

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laurenz Albe. Can I ask you how would you deal with this formula if we also add backup and replication activity (lets say physical one slave). Because in that case I think we should add some more memory

Comment: Not really, since replication doesn't use memory worth mentioning.